# Actionscript : Variable not found from another class' function

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables, actionscript, global-variables

I tried doing

```
trace(classname.functionname.variablename);
//or
trace(classname.functionname().variablename);
```

Didn't work.. any idea, to get from the classname.as the variable, that's inside a function?
Btw i tried making the function static, still didn't work
Any idea?

Comment: Please provide more code. To access variables outside a class you need to make them public properties. I suspect you want to access variables inside a function body which is not doable since they won't exist until the function is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way, as those variables that are defined inside a function only live as long as the function is executed, and disappear once there's a `return` or end of function body. In order to get whatever value you want from a function, make a class variable outside the function, assign it the value you want within that function, and address it from elsewhere.

```
class test {
public static var foo:Number;
function bar():void {
    // ... some code
    foo=baz*2.54;
    // ... more code
}
}
class elsewhere {
    ...
    trace(test.foo);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thougt it was an easy way.. anyway thanks :) i will make it with the hard way :P

Answer (score 0):

the variables created inside a function are only available in the scope of that function.
if the variables are class member variables (declared public on a class);

```
public class x {
 public var varName:String="";
}
```

you will be able to access them as

```
classInstanceRef.varName
```

needless to say you will need to instantiate from that class an instance.

Unless your variable is declared static on the class

```
public static varName:String="";
```

and in that case you can access it using

```
className.varName;
```

Comment: What you mean with ClassInstanceRef